# pesky popular "No input file specified." with nginx_php-fastcgi

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I didn't have this problem earlier until I changed the include path on my php.ini in hopes of being able to upload to a dir outside the docroot. When I encountered the "No input file specified." error I changed it back to the default php.ini and now it won't go away!

Any ideas on what might've happened?

Comment: would like to see this problem solved without calling back to apache

Comment: I bet you were using Godaddy's hosting

Comment: Ha nope. This was actually on an EC2 instance

Answer (score 4):

in file /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

change

user: nginx

group:nginx

Comment: This fixed it for me! I had to edit `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/app.conf`. I have multiple pools so the user/group needed to be appuser/appuser. I had it set to appuser/www-data and that caused the problem.

Comment: This fixed for me too. My case was that I was using vagrant and php 7 with FPM. So I had to edit /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf and changed the user and group to vagrant.

Answer (score 0):

Edit nginx.conf

```
http{
....
server{
....
location ~ \.php$ {
        root           html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  D:\WebRoot\www\$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}}
```

replace D:\WebRoot\www\ with the root of your webserver