# No input file specified - apache and php-fastcgi

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My client's website is currently running on a apache server with mod_php. All application's routes are defined in the .htaccess file (see the code below). Now he is trying to migrate to an server running apache and php-fastcgi, but the routes are no long working.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On

  # Redirect
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
  RewriteRule "^noticias/?$" index.php/noticias/frontend/list/ [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

When I access http://domain.tld/noticias, I get `No input file specified`, and in the apache error_log `[fcgid:warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  Unknown: function '1' not found or invalid function name in Unknown on line 0`, but if I access the route directly http://domain.tld/index.php/noticias/frontend/list/ it works fine.

**UPDATE**

I found a working solution changing some of the framework behaviour. If someone has a solution without having to change the framework (probably in the apache or php configuration), I will gadly award the answer the bounty.

Comment: is mod_rewrite installed on the new server?

Comment: @Pipe Yes, I ran other tests to check this.

Comment: Which hosting you are using ?

Comment: @Bugfixer We are currently using an EC2 instances

Comment: @LucasFerreira - check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297421/pesky-popular-no-input-file-specified-with-nginx-php-fastcgi)

Comment: One [more](http://serverfault.com/questions/426722/ec2-micro-with-nginx)

Comment: Is [cgi.fix_pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.cgi.fix-pathinfo) enabled?

Comment: @user3584460 Yes, it's enabled.

Comment: Try adding `?` after index.php as per the following solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118740/codeigniter-no-input-file-specified

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As sugested by @user3584460, I decided to change all my routes to pass the desired controller/action as a querystring parameter. Here how it was done.

I changed all routes to pass a _url parameter:

```
RewriteRule "^noticias/?$" index.php?_url=/noticias/frontend/list/ [L,QSA]
```

This way I would not get the error "No input file specified", but the framework (zend) would not recognize the route, and would always show the homepage.

The route dispatcher expected the `$requestUri` variable to be in the format `index.php/module/controller/action`, but with the change in the `.htaccess`, it was `index.php?_url=/module/controller/action`. So I had to make some changes in the `Zend_Controller_Request_Http` class, so it would make the conversion.

So I added the following lines to the `setRequestUri` method:

```
public function setRequestUri($requestUri = null)
{
    // ...

    // begin changes
    preg_match('/_url=([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-_\.]+)&?(.*)/', $requestUri, $matches);
    if (count($matches) == 3)
        $requestUri = '/index.php' . $matches[1] . '?' . $matches[2];
    // end changes

    $this->_requestUri = $requestUri;
    return $this;
}
```

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Change your line with `noticias`:

```
  RewriteRule ^noticias/?$ index.php/noticias/frontend/list/ [L]
```

Comment: Still the same error, and I need the flag QSA to have access to the query string parameters.

Comment: No need to add `[QSA]` without new query string. But I see you have corrected your question

Answer (score 2):

We sometimes see this on sites that use rewrites. We fixed this by changing the rewrite. The old line would be something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ _routing.php/$1 [L]
```

We changed it into:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ _routing.php [L]
```

This resolved the issue.

Comment: It did work but I am wondering why? It happened with me apache and PHP 8.0 fast CGI

Comment: Also adding a question mark after php file name like this  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]` solves the issue