# Symfony - install on a CentOS server

Tags: php, apache, symfony, centos

I'm trying to install Symfony for the first time, following the official [guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html). So, installing the symfony installer went smoothly, then running `symfony new my_project_name` creates the folder under `/home/myuser/public_html/my_project_name`. Then, trying to open `mydomain.com` results in a `403 Forbidden` page. If I try to open `mydomain.com/my_project_name` it's also a `403 Forbidden`.

Looking in the Apache configuration, I see user apache and group apache. So I'm trying to `chown` the whole project folder to `apache.apache` - doesn't help.

Tried to run `composer install` or `composer update` - doesn't help either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your virtual host is pointing to `your_project_dir/web` ?

Comment: no, I need to change th virtualhost ?

Comment: seems right ! thanks. I now have `No input file specified.`

Comment: If it can help someone someday, the `No input file specified` error came from a bunch of configuration virtualmin added to the virtualhost. Removing them and sticking to a simple virtualhost like the guide provided by @HypeR did the trick !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the official guide on how to setup the web server for apache / nginx : https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

You might be missing something in your virtualhost.

The "no input file specified" seems to be related to an .htaccess issue.
Related topic : [No input file specified - apache and php-fastcgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255289/no-input-file-specified-apache-and-php-fastcgi)